# handle the alert event with the radio button checked, react JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

here is my doubt, have to handle the alert event with the radio button checked, if the radio button is not checked then the row can delete without any warning or alert

the below program does have a table with a add button which adds a row to the table when the button is clicked. and inside the row the remove button which removes the particular row.

but the problem is if the radio button is clicked in the specific row then the row should not delete and should show an alert box that the radio button is clicked!

```
{import header}
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: [{}]
  };
  handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      name: "",
      mobile: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  handleRemoveSpecificRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows]
    rows.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState({ rows })
  }
  render() {
    return (
              <table
                className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                id="tab_logic"
              >
                
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
                      {/* <td>{idx}</td> */}
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="name"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].name}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].mobile}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <Button
                          className="btn btn-sm"
                          onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
                        >
                          Remove
                        </Button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>           
    );
  }
}
```

many thanks in advance! watch out for the radio button code

Comment: Where are you checking the property that radio button is checked before deleting a row?

Comment: i have to check but, i dont know where?

Comment: Inside handleRemoveSpecificRow method

Comment: You can check this via checked attribute of the radio button